# Breaking an azeotrope by using different atmospheres?

Tags: distillation

I read the threads about azeotropic mixtures and distillation, and a question arose:

Is it possible to distill an azeotropic mixtures properly (i. e., separate it into its single components) by changing the atmosphere? For example, if you distill under argon atmosphere or gaseous hydrogen chloride?

Best and stay healthy!

Wolf

Comment: I can't see the point of using something like that. Also questions aren't letters.

Comment: Sorry for not being more precise, but this question is work related:-) But I think, my question is obsolete: If you heat up the mixture to its boiling point, its vapor pressure increases to atmospheric pressure and will therefore replace the atmosphere by its own components, right? So, no effect would be visible as soon as youre mixture starts to boil.

Comment: That's also not true. Read up on things like equilibrium vapor pressure.

Comment: Okay, so, you mean, there could be a chance, that an azeotropic mixture can be separated into its single components?

Comment: If the gas reacts with one of the components like HCl you just mentioned, then sure. Otherwise, pressure works but not different gases. Sometimes, it changes compositions for non azeotropic mixture like distilling NMP in N2 vs air at atmospheric pressure (which I suspect is more due to degradation) but I've never seen azeotropes go through any change.